# Send Soap Request over Net.tcp with postman

Tags: wcf, postman, net.tcp

I have a WCF Soap service that I am testing using postman. The developer currently has to expose an additional HTTPs end point for use to test against as the actual bindings are Net.TCP.

Is there a way I can test Net.TCP endpoint using postman?

I've looked on line but I cannot find an answer

Help much appreciated

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: net.tcp is a WCF construct - I don't think Postman would know what it is.   You're probably stuck with using an http endpoint.  Or you could use the WCF Test Client, which does understand net.tcp.

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked [the same question in the postman community](https://community.getpostman.com/t/using-postman-to-test-a-net-tcp-wcf-soap-service/1498) and got an answer, I thougth it would be nice to have it here as well.

The user [abhinav](https://community.getpostman.com/u/abhinav) answered Apr 30 2018:

> Not yet. We only support HTTP/HTTPS right now.